# Dropping a rope in a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, string

If there is a spaceship hovering above a black hole so that it can get away, what would happen if the spaceship connected a rope to itself and dropped the rope in? Could you pull the rope out?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126929/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No amount of force can pull anything out of a black hole. Hopefully the rope will break, or you can release it, before your ship gets pulled in.