# What will happen to Earth if it's tied to a black hole thru a really strong string?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, string

Imagine a very strong string (with infinity as as its breaking point)
attached to earth very strongly and the other end is put inside a black hole,

1. What will happen to Earth?
2. And the string?
3. Will it never fall into black hole because of spaghettification or would something else happen

Sorry for silly question

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104474/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather unphysical.

Problem one: The speed of sound in the cable cannot exceed $c$, therefore its strength is limited by the very principles of relativistic physics (or it has to get denser, but then it will at some point have sufficient energy density to collapse to a black hole itself). (This argument can be made sharp, I think it can be found somewhere in Landau, Lifshitz II: Classical Field Theory, the puzzle pieces are there for sure).

Problem two: If we assume such a cable would be consistent with relativistics, the pull on the cable would not be that strong, as the surface gravity of a black hole (the gravity at the event horizon) is not large (and especially getting *weaker* for larger black holes).

Problem three: How to get the cable "linked" to the black hole, for an observer at infinity it takes infinite time for an object to reach the event horizon.

So the best answer is, this situation would never arise (but feel free to send this question as input to [What If](https://what-if.xkcd.com/), if Randall Munroe chooses to answer, I am convinced it will be hilarious!).